# Maven plugin to execute other plugins?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

Is there a maven plugin that executes other maven plugins? I swear there was one and now I can not find it.

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just reference those other plugins directly from the pom?

Comment: Because putting them in your pom doesn't necessarily call them. You may have to invoke them directly, or indirectly during a phase. Whereas if you have a plugin that calls other plugins you can "chain them together".

Answer (score 3):

If you don't find anything else, you could always write your own with the help of [The Mojo Executer](https://github.com/TimMoore/mojo-executor). It's a library that allows you to easily write plugins that invoke other plugins.

I'm still not quite sure I understand your answer to Waldheinz though. Maybe you could explain exactly *why* you need to do this? Maybe there's an alternative solution that doesn't involve chaining plugins.

Comment: One scenario would be to turn your Java application into a Windows service. For that, you need to download the WinSW executable or something similar, create an XML file for WinSW, create batch files to start, stop, install and uninstall the service, and package everything into a ZIP file. Practically everything in these steps can be templated and take values from the POM file, but it has to be done for every service. It would be nice to just be able to include a plugin that does all this without any fuss.